# regarding vertex function and proton scattering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering-cross-section

I am currently going through electromagnetic form factor. I came across the fact that since the proton is not an elementary particle its scattering(elastic) with electron can be modeled using general general electromagnetic form factor of form

$ \Gamma_{\mu} = \gamma_{\mu}F_1(q^2) + i\sigma_{\mu\lambda}q^{\lambda}F_2(q^2)\\ $

where we get scattering amplitude and cross section in terms of $ F_1, F_2 $.

So there are two questions

1. Is this the general procedure actually followed while present day experiment for calculating the amplitude or is there another (better) method?
2. Can I do the same for scattering of electron with  pions (which are spin 0) using corresponding general vertex function(which i think would have only 1 form factor ,i suppose)?